# console use db use error

Tags: mysql

I am working in the mysql console and trying to use a db that has a naming convention that is so: `xxx-xxxx`. When I try to use the db I get an error and it seems to be that the "-" is the cause of the issue. I run mysql use `xxx-xxxx` and get the error. How would I overcome this so I can use the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quote mysql names (tables, columns, databases) with backticks.

So the query

```
use `xxx-xxxx`;
```

should work for you.